# Is there a way to stop useMutation from setting `data` to `undefined` before updating it to a new value?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have a mock mutation like so:

```
interface Person {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

async function sendPersonApi({ firstName, lastName }: Person) {
  await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, 1000));
  return {
    firstName,
    lastName,
    status: "success"
  };
}
```

I have two components: `<Form />` and `<Output />`. I basically want the mutation to run on form submit of the `<Form />`, and then show the result of that mutation in the `<Output />`.

I have a CodeSandbox with this behavior mostly working: https://codesandbox.io/s/long-worker-k350q?file=/src/App.tsx

**Form**

```
const personAtom = atom<Person>({
  firstName: "",
  lastName: ""
});

function Form() {
  const [formState, setFormState] = useAtom(personAtom);

  const handleSubmit: FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement> = useCallback(
    (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      const formElement = event.currentTarget;
      const formData = new FormData(formElement);
      const firstName = formData.get("firstName") as string;
      const lastName = formData.get("lastName") as string;
      setFormState({ firstName, lastName }); // This does not update the `data`/`isLoading`/`isError` in the <Output /> component
    },
    [setFormState]
  );

  return (
    <form id="name-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input name="firstName" /> <br />
      <input name="lastName" /> <br />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

**Output**

```
function Output() {
  const [person] = useAtom(personAtom);
  const { mutate, data,  isLoading, isError } = useMutation(sendPersonApi, {
    mutationKey: "sendPerson"
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    mutate(person);
  }, [person]);

  return (
    <output name="name-output" form="name-form">
      <p>data: {JSON.stringify(data)}</p>
      <p>isLoading: {JSON.stringify(isLoading)}</p>
      <p>isError: {JSON.stringify(isError)}</p>
    </output>
  );
}
```

Initially, I had wanted to implement this by doing the mutation itself inside the `<Form />` submit handler, but it seems like I was not be able to access the `data`/`isLoading`/`isError` in a different component even if I used the same `mutationKey` in `useMutation`.

So I ended up changing the implementation so that the submit handler just updates some global state (using `jotai` atoms), and then in the `Output` I have an effect that listens for changes to this global state and then calls `mutate()`.

The problem now though is that the `data` always gets reset to `undefined` in every subsequent submit before getting a new value. Is there a way to stop `useMutation` from setting `data` to `undefined` before updating it to a new value?

Also, is there a cleaner way of using the result of a mutation in another component? I'd prefer to have the `mutate()` done inside the `Form` and then somehow use the `data`/`isLoading`/`isError` in a different component without having to rely on `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm going to just create a separate `atom` to hold the global state for the current `data`. Then I'll use the `onSuccess` of the `useMutation` to update this global state from within `<Form />` and then just use that global state inside `<Output />`.